# Did this answer require the OP to disclose affiliation?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51582245/4875631), which attracted a bit of attention due to the fact the username was similar to the website in question.

The original answer, which was posted by the developer of the library:

> You can't change the endValue of a DOTweenAnimation, but you can
>   change the endValue of the tween it generates using
>   [ChangeEndValue][1]:
>
> ```
> myTween = myDOTweenAnimation.GetTweens()[0];
> myTween.ChangeEndValue("something else");
> ```
>
> [1]:
>   http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php?api=ChangeEndValue

The original question asked a question directly about this library, and this answer simply links to the official documentation for this. Was attribution really needed in this case?

Comment: It is quite common for companies and library owners to support their product/library at SO.  As true for small companies as big ones, Microsoft has many dozens of employees that answer questions for example.  Many more examples of this.  It is not promotional when the question asks about it.

Comment: @HansPassant There is a difference between a random Microsoft employee posting an answer about a product they have not worked on, and the developer of a library posting a link to a site they fully control (note: the site asks for donations and has a paid level of product). That the developer is here supporting their product is great, but requires disclosure of affiliation. Frankly, I don't see why a developer *wouldn't* want to disclose that they wrote the library. I'd consider it a significant plus to see that a developer cared enough to be answering questions.

Comment: Disclosing this in the user's profile is the common approach, he does as well.

Comment: @Makyen There is a difference between saying "you can solve your problem by using X library (that I am not disclosing that I am a associated with)" and a question that is asked about the library and answered by someone associated with it. The link is to the documentation for a thing being asked about. Would an MDN contributor have to disclose their affiliation when answering a JavaScript question and linking to the relevant documentation on MDN? I fail to see how disclosure can be required or even beneficial on this. It seems like nothing more than pure noise to me.

Comment: I'm the developer in question, and I'd like to add my point of view. @Makyen you wonder why a developer wouldn't disclose they wrote a library. Well, at least in my case, it feels a little pompous (which doesn't mean it is, it's just my personal view). Like, "Hey, here I come, I did this so I have all the right answers." It seems kind of awkward. But that said, I understand that I'm a newbie on SO, and I also understand what generates this kind of discussion and really appreciate it.

Comment: @Demigiant So I would say in the future, you're going to be fine if you don't wish to post attribution. I originally marked the question as "not a problem" in smokey (The bot that triggered users to your post in the first place), and I think most users would as well.

Comment: Its also hard to hide your affiliation when your user name matches exactly. ;) @Demigiant Just want to say that DOTween is an awesome asset and use it for small animations all the time.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If someone is asking about how to do something with a specific framework or product, and one of the authors / contributors / employees of that framework or product answer, I don't think disclosure is required. It can sometimes help lend authority to an answer ("I wrote that, and here's how this works"), but I don't see it as a requirement. Similarly, I don't have a problem with links back to the source documentation on their site, as long as the answer had enough content outside of that link.

Disclosure is recommended or required in cases where the answerer is suggesting the use of their framework or product to a question that does not specifically ask for it. I wrote up [some of my personal guidelines for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229085/how-to-offer-personal-open-source-libraries#229091) a while ago.

This is something I come up against regularly, because I have a moderately popular open source library that I answer questions about here, and do occasionally run into cases where it might be the best solution for a given problem. When someone's asking about problems with my framework, I have no trouble answering that without disclosing that I'm the author. Similarly, I'll often link back to core documentation or code on the repository, and I don't have a problem linking to blog posts I've written about specific issues in response to questions about them. However, if they weren't asking about my framework to begin with, I try to make sure I fully disclose that I'm the author of what I'm suggesting. At the least, that makes my bias clear.

I'm fine with the answer in its original state. The added disclaimer they edited in afterward doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: Do you think we should modify this [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)? Currently this is used to flag anything without affiliation as spam (specially if it is simple to see affiliation as same username in GitHub link).

Comment: @PetterFriberg, that FAQ post needs has to be modified a lot. It also completely [misinterprets ChrisF's answer which talks about chances of a post being spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303698/how-to-deal-with-an-otherwise-salvageable-post-with-a-spam-link). Fortunately, we don't get many spam flags because of that reason.