# Why was this answer deleted by a mod?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29169135/7910454

[image]

Seems totally fine to me and even has 5 upvotes.

Comment: The answer is nothing more than a quote. From [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): _"In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."_

Comment: @Larnu I understand but shouldn't a strict enforcement of the rules sometimes be deferred in favor of providing a useful answer? The only reason my question was answered is because I can see deleted posts :/

Comment: There are *maybe* rare occasions, but even *some* of your own wording should be in the answer, in my opinion; even if that is to summarise the quote block in your own words. Adding a couple of sentences to summarise the quote, or using the quote to validate your statement instead, just means that the answer is not entirely someone's content.

Comment: Yes, however, cases like these should at minimum be corrected... the mod (or anyone with 50 or more rep) could have left a comment on the answer requesting it be corrected, but there's no requirement for that to occur before being "cleaned up"

Comment: The answer is essentially plagiarism. It's sourced, yes, and it would've been fine if the quote was used to back up OPs statements, but that wasn't the case here. The equivalent here is handing in a research paper that's 100% quoted from another paper or other form of source. "research paper" in this case can also be replaced with uni/school assignment, or anything else where your work is expected to be original. The same logic extends to Stack posts. Without the quote, it'd be a link-only answer, which we also don't allow. The only person who can fix it is OP, and that assumes they want to

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Minor point: I don't see how this is "essentially plagiarism". Doesn't plagiarism require at least some degree of passing off the content as one's own? From the help-center: "*posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own*". In this answer, there's a link, the copied text is quoted, and the answer literally says "copied here". It should be deleted for not having any original content, for sure, but I don't see how the the answer can be described as plagiarism at all.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine There is a tiny difference: SO is not a research journal. As long as answer gives credit to the original source and contains all necessary information to remain useful in case the link rots, it should be OK.

Comment: Indeed, Plagiarism is defined as using someone else's work and passing it off as your own; even if you don't cite the original source but put the text in a quote block it's not strictly speaking plagiarism, but it doesn't meet the sites guidelines/rules regarding using content that isn't your own has citation and isn't the entire basis of your post.

Comment: Fair enough, but we still don't allow these types of posts, as outlined in /help/referencing

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I understand where you are coming from but I really think you should try to take a step back and think about how you want to impact this community. The answer was obviously helping people and you take that away from them because you allege "sourced plagiarism" of open-source documentation? Is that a practical and solution-oriented approach to community moderation?

Comment: According to [one of plagiarism.org's definitions](https://www.plagiarism.org/article/what-is-plagiarism): *"copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not (see our section on "fair use" rules)"* - it's still plagiarism, English is weird.

Comment: @leonheess This is one of our many rules [that are clearly outlined and documented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing); posts only consisting of copy-pasta are subject to deletion, regardless of whether or not english can make up its mind on what it considers plagiarism to be. Also, even if OP doesn't return to edit their answer, you can still write your own answer to replace it

Comment: @leonheess Making exceptions for "helpful" content opens an entire truckload of worms. Moderators are there to enforce the rules; any salvaging they can do along the way is extra. The practical and solution-oriented approach is that *you* edit the answer or write a new one to get the content into shape.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine No offense, but I don't think you understand me (or want to?). It's not about this specific question that obviously could be fixed. It's about the fact that parts of the moderation on this site are totally fine with leaving a question worse off and less helpful than they have found it. Maybe you should strive to make this community better and more helpful instead of striving the be the rule police.

Comment: @leonheess If it's not about the specific question, then please edit your question to be more general, e.g. "should questions like this be deleted?" A discussion can certainly be had about whether it's beneficial to the site to delete such questions, or not, but currently the rules are to delete such questions. Mods *are* supposed to enforce the current rules, and if you want to change the rules you need community support to do that. (Make sure to see if there are duplicate discussions about this on Meta.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No rule book is perfect and accounts for everything. That is why it is so important that rules are applied with sanity and reason. That is true for rules in the real world and on SO. I'd much rather have moderation that judges every case by itself and is therefore slightly inconsistent than one that destroys value in the name of order and consistency.

Comment: @leonheess The rule book accounts for this case by allowing the community to salvage the content, so I really don't see why the rules should be bent. Expecting moderators to salvage everything possible just isn't realistic with the workload at SO.

Comment: For link-only answers, we request that they put the bit from the link they're referring to into the answer (to avoid link rot). But now we also delete their post after they do that (for only including a quote). This is like a catch-22 when the answer to the question posed is basically "you didn't read the documentation so let me spoon feed it to you".

Comment: Does the fact that the source doesn't exist anymore change anything? Sure, it was plagiarism when it was posted, but here we are 7 years later and that source no longer exists. Did it exist 7 months ago? If the answer was simply edited to state what was quoted, there'd be no evidence that it's plagiarized and no source to prove it with.

Comment: @KevinB it doesn't not exist, it has just [moved](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/create-packages#how-do-i-exclude-executables-from-getting-shims).

Comment: Fair. but as a hypothetical?

Comment: (Un)fortunately, once something is on the internet, it rarely disappears from it in some form, @KevinB . In this case, the edit history would show that the content previously cited an external source and had the content in a block quote. *Had* the content been lacking citation and or formatting, then one would hope that someone would have picked up on the (malicious) plagiarism at the time. There are *normally* enough of us that detect it, and users that do plagiarise tend to make it a habit.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it explicitly answers the question to me.

Comment: And as a Community we can't undo it! `A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted`

Comment: The thing here is that the user that posted the answer could have given a simple link as a comment and state where to find that quote in that same comment. Sometimes a simple comment can "answer" the question, and be left there so people can redirect to where the answer is, without converting the link into an SO answer.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Exactly why I believe moderators should only be exception handlers. If they're doing review queues or stuff what normal users do, they should do only what other users can do. They should use their powers only under exceptional circumstances or when a issue is brought by users.

Comment: In this case, it seems the moderator was doing a review queue and found someone [improving the post:re linked the doc and added some code](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30559647). I think the edit improves the post and should've been accepted. If the code added conflicts with the author's intent, the moderator could've used "Edit and Accept" button to remove the code, but keep the changed documentation link. Removing old links and adding the new link is clearly a improvement. Instead, the mod went on to delete everything, clearly a disservice to the community, in this case.

Comment: @JeremyThompson currently we can't undelete it and it's correct! (no reason to undelete/delete back an forth during meta discussion), however if this discussion, most upvoted answer is pro undeleting, moderators will undelete. So just vote on the answer with your preferred outcome.

Comment: The post appears to have been undeleted

Comment: @mousetail Check the first comment on the accepted answer

Comment: If an author wants people to quote and reference their work, they are harmed by this kind of approach. We should do some basic investigation on the substantiality, authorship, and if needed notifying the original author. Takedown notices exist because not every author wants their work purged from the internet. Assuming we know best about what the author wants is needlessly hostile to authors who want to share their work. In this case, the answer was written by the original author and had we gone a little slower, did some investigation, it might have been discovered before it was removed.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Would your opinion be different (in a different case where the author of the answer wasn't the one who wrote the quoted docs) if the answer had been posted as community wiki?  Non-CW would generate SO reputation for the poster, and perhaps that form of "credit" was what led you to mentally group this with plagiarism.  (Finding and reposting relevant pre-existing work with attribution isn't plagiarism, but it doesn't require new effort unless the finding process was difficult.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Not for off-site content, no. Also not for other answers on SO/SE. Moving comments (on the question the answer is posted to) to answers, however, [are an established exception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/6296561) to this. As far as I'm aware, it's also the only exception. Plagiarism doesn't magically become not plagiarism just because it's a community wiki

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Quoting *with attribution* is not plagiarism.  As discussed in earlier comments, that [word specifically means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) passing off someone else's work as your own. (Or self-plagiarism if you repost your own work as new effort instead of citing an earlier article you wrote.)  Quote-formatting explicitly indicates text that you *didn't* just write while answering.  I didn't realize you were still arguing that this was actual plagiarism; earlier you replied "fair enough" when people pointed out it wasn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes quoting the Wikipedia page you conveniently linked to, "Relying too heavily on other people's work, failing to bring original thought into the text.", under forms of academic plagiarism. The page [Nick linked to earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419330/why-was-this-answer-deleted-by-a-mod?noredirect=1#comment919094_419330) has a similar definition, though fully decoupled from an academic context. Pure copy-pasta is covered by the definition of plagiarism; feel free to continue to deny that against several sources, but it's an established definition regardless

Comment: My "fair enough" was back when I questioned whether I had screwed on on the definition of plagiarism or not. I hadn't, though my use may be a lot more academically oriented, but it's one that's arguably covered by the help center. The help center doesn't explicitly specify it doesn't follow the academic definitions, either explicitly or by providing a concrete definition of what this site considers plagiarism. The definition is further backed up by the help center stating that pure copy-pasta, regardless of attribution, is subject to deletion. Regardless of whether we label it plagiarism,

Comment: _that rule applies_. Pure copy-pasta is subject to deletion, and I made a judgement call favoring deletion. I believe the undeletion was a mistake, but honestly, this isn't a hill I'm going to die on, and I'm done discussing it.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Thanks for pointing out that more detailed definition of plagiarism, now I understand what you're talking about.  Note that lacking original effort is a form of *academic* plagiarism, where every article or other scholarly contribution is expected to be *new* original work.  Stack Overflow answers don't have that requirement, especially not community-wiki ones (where e.g. collecting up comments into a CW answer is generally accepted.)  For SO to apply that standard of originality, would we have to consider any question a duplicate if it had an answer anywhere online?

Comment: @PeterCordes "The help center doesn't explicitly specify it doesn't follow the academic definitions, either explicitly or by providing a concrete definition of what this site considers plagiarism.", "The page Nick linked to earlier has a similar definition, **though fully decoupled from an academic context**". And again, **regardless of plagiarism definitions** for one word I apparently shouldn't have used to prevent that from becoming the one thing that gets used repeatedly in the defense of the answer, **the help center states pure copy-pasta answers are subject to deletion**

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: I agree that *usually* an answer that's just a quote with attribution is a bad answer.  But I think there can be exceptions.  (Especially in this case, where the person was quoting themselves, as they wrote the docs they're quoting.)  Sometimes applying your standard is a sign that the *question* is bad (answerable with a quote from the docs that doesn't need further interpretation / explanation).  IDK if that was the case here, I didn't look at the actual Q&A, but there can be cases where different phrasing can be a useful signpost for future searches.

Comment: There isn't a strict standard on originality in the definition you seem to be using, but SO answers are expected to be original in the sense that it isn't just copy-pasta from another source. It can be _based_ on other sources by, quoting [the help center](/help/referencing): "[using] their words and ideas to support your own", which wasn't the case with this answer, regardless of CW status, and regardless of the concrete definition of plagiarism

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Agreed we can put the word "plagiarism" to rest; what matters most here is what any given answer's existence means for the quality and usefulness of SO as a resource for future readers. And perhaps to some degree credit in the form of rep for users who post such answers, hence CW being relevant.  The written guidelines certainly *allow* deletion of such answers, but as others have pointed out on this meta, the phrasing (and implicit social contract for mods?) leaves room for judgment calls on the value of any individual post.

Comment: Often such an answer is better than nothing, and can be left alone unless it starts to be a pattern in a subject area or for a certain user.  (And rarely, like perhaps in this case, it's actually a good answer to a low quality question, and there's nothing more to add.)  TL:DR: Please don't get carried away interpreting written rules in ways that wipes out useful work people have done finding and quoting+linking relevant material, @Zoe.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine *Regardless of whether we label it plagiarism, that rule applies. Pure copy-pasta is subject to deletion, and I made a judgement call favoring deletion. I believe the undeletion was a mistake*. The help center does say it is subject to deletion, but not always. There are cases where deletion is unnecessary is implied. You say you made a judgment call. The "pure copy paste" brings it subject to this rule. Once it is under this rule, due to "pure copy paste", what factors did you consider, before  making the judgment call, deciding deletion or status quo?

Comment: The canonical is *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)* - e.g., *"copying entire texts wholesale is incredibly frowned upon"*.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine The overwhelming part of this community has decided they would much rather have a helpful answer, the answers given here illustrate that it doesn't require any rule bending to let the answer live and your own colleague has undeleted it. Yet you are still in the comments arguing about semantics and showing no sign of introspection...

Comment: Jesus, nobody cares, a below average answer got deleted, discussed and undeleted, people disagree, move along. As for "still in the comments arguing", people respond when pinged, what a surprise.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine This question was just  recently closed as "not suitable for site" and reopened, pushing it to the top.  The problem isn't this answer. It's about strict rule policing -  at any cost. It's worth discussing about. Also, your characterization of the answer as "below average" is part of the problem.

Comment: Really? We're gonna go the sneaky "oh actually this isn't just about this case" route? In that case, my care level would rise a lot...

Comment: @TheMaster if you want to have a broader discussion, that should occur in another meta post. This post is about a specific question that, given the circumstances, is quite abnormal.

Comment: Why can't we discuss the specifics of this question on a broader note? The accepted answer already references another canonical  and BoltClock's  agreement on the issue. All of the answers are about the interpretations of help center article page. It was already discussed on a broader note than this specific questions' intricacies. There's nothing specific about this question: It's about deletion of quote only answers, which actually answers the question.

Comment: @TheMaster Because this question isn't going to result in a policy change, due to it being about a specific scenario that isn't your avg every day plagiarism case. Exceptions do exist and often don't get handled exactly the same as everything else.

Comment: @KevinB Policy has always been the same. But some sections of meta disagree that such quotes are unacceptable and deleted a good answer. This is about policy clarification. Nothing else. You can't restrict it  to "Oh it's only about specifics of this question"

Comment: We also can't simply say it's settled policy based on a few meta posts when the way these have *actually* been handled in the real world doesn't match that "policy". Posts get deleted for plagiarism every day, the policy as you describe it effectively says plagiarism is 100% allowed in all scenarios.

Comment: @TheMaster "Why can't we discuss the specifics of this question on a broader note?" Because we *haven't* and silently reframing what has been said would be insincere. A lot of things were said with only that specific case in mind. A lot of things were not said with the general case in mind. A lot of people just disengaged because one answer isn't a hill worth dying on.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  I respectfully disagree. The only thing that is discussed, in relation to the specifics of this answer was that the author quoted himself( which is not even highlighted in the accepted answer). Other than that, we were discussing official policies, quoting previous canonicals, previous moderator positions and interpreting official help centre articles. You can't just restrict that to just  "this one answer".  Why was this answer deleted? This answer was deleted, because of a existing policy interpretation. The consensus show how that policy was interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinB If you think I'm saying "plagiarism is 100% allowed in all scenarios", you're not hearing me(or any of the other answers) at all. Just yesterday, I flagged a post for plagiarism. I flag whenever I'm able to. What we are saying is "Quoting the official docs  and linking it properly is NOT plagiarism and shouldn't be deleted, even if that's the only thing that's present in that answer". It's always been the official policy. If it was handled  differently in the real world, then the real world handling is done wrongly. And everyone of that actions should be retracted.

Comment: @TheMaster The current accepted answer is along the lines of "usually deletion would be okay but in a case like this it is not". So this seems to be very much about "this answer". If you want to make this more general, we would have to discuss what that general case even is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, it is about this answer. But what aspect of this answer is considered? Why do the consensus think this answer  should not be deleted? When a quote any answer 1. properly quotes the official documentation with attribution, and 2. the quote completely answers the question,  the deletion is unwarranted. This is what BoltClock's quote in the answer is also saying. That general policy is what is discussed. In contrast, Zoe is suggesting every quote only answer is plagiarism and should be deleted. That policy interpretation is where we differ: "every" vs "often/most".

Comment: To quote Boltclock, **Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said than one or two well-written paragraphs from a documentation section or a language specification. That's fine** Does the opposition agree that that's fine? That's the only issue here. Does the opposition agree that there are cases, where that's fine and the deletion is unwarranted? Zoe doesn't seem to acknowledge that there are cases like this, where it's fine.

Comment: If Zoe can suggest why they deleted the post other than it being a "pure copy paste", we can see their point of view. Like what factors did they consider other than it being a quote only answer. Under what circumstances would they not have deleted a pure copy/paste quote only answer?

Comment: @TheMaster I don't see Zoe suggesting any such thing, on account of not participating in this discussion much past the initial not-quite-friendly welcome. The devil is in the details, in the end. There is quite some way between "it is fine", "you won't get into trouble" to "it does not have to be deleted".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Why would a "fine" answer be deleted? "Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said". If there isn't "much more to be said", why  should there be a reason to delete such answers, because there isn't "much more"?

Comment: @TheMaster "fine" isn't meant to rate what the answer says but how. Giving a correct answer in the wrong way isn't fine, not just with respect to attribution. Usefulness isn't the only criteria that applies; since mod decisions are usually made without subject matter expertise, I dare say it should apply very little.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not sure you're debating in good faith.  It's not just the correct answer.  The consensus here and in the past, shows it was given in the correct way. I ask again, Do you really believe there are some situations where there isn't much more to be said except a quote, as said by Boltclock: "Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said".

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, such situations exist – *so what?* A lot of good and bad situations exist for the Q&A format; mere existence is meaningless. If you allege bad faith on my side, please show the courtesy of not using such loaded, open questions yourself right afterwards. I'm not in the mood to tug on rope intended to hang myself, but if the alternative is that disengagement is misrepresented as consensus I will...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas and that's why the "rules" need to account people that apply them blindly without understanding why does it exist and when it should be applied.

Comment: Granted reading through all the comments from an outsider's point of view appears Herculean but @ZoestandswithUkraine the following footnote was deleted by an editor "Disclosure: I am the original author of the documentation I linked to above.” Isn't knowing who the author of the quoted piece appropriate and fitting? Shouldn't all citations be attributed? I don't understand the editor's motivation `We don't ask Jon Skeet to disclosure when he quotes documentation, we aren't going to start now.` Why wouldn't you want to know if JS was the author of a piece that he quotes at length from?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Our policy has always been to discourage quote-only answers on the basis that *usually* an ideal answer to a question will consist of more than just a quote from the docs. But we've never outright forbidden quote-only answers, in part because *sometimes* a quote from an external source *does* completely answer the question, and there's nothing more that can be usefully added.

Consider the example of good quoting from the [Referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) docs:

> According to [Ernest Hemingway - Biographical on Nobelprize.org](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1954/hemingway-bio.html), Hemingway saw combat when he was a teenager. It says:
>
> > After the United States entered the First World War, he joined a volunteer ambulance unit in the Italian army. Serving at the front, he was wounded, was decorated by the Italian Government, and spent considerable time in hospitals  ....
>
> *[other sources, quotes, explanations, etc. necessary to complete the answer]*

Well, what happens if in fact the quote is a sufficient answer to the question already? Then no other "sources, quotes, explanations, etc." *are* "necessary" to complete the answer, and so, strictly speaking, the "*[other sources, quotes, explanations, etc. necessary to complete the answer]*" section can and should be empty. And then - as a result of *strictly following the instructions in the Help Center* - you're left with exactly the kind of quote-only answer that this Meta question is about.

Boltclock endorsed the position that quote-only answers are okay back when he was a mod - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321326/1709587:

> Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said than one or two well-written paragraphs from a documentation section or a language specification. That's fine, you're not going to get into trouble for doing that every now and then. Just remember that you still need to provide attribution and quote the text as required above.

Boltclock's position is consistent with the official rules in the help center, which don't at any point say that quote-only answers are outright banned or *must* be deleted. It also seems to me like common sense. After all, what's the alternative? Is ferventcoder supposed to quote the official docs *and also* include a paraphrase of them? Why? What purpose would be served by that?

The answer should be undeleted.

Comment: I tend to agree with the consensus here. The answer is an actual answer and the existing guidance about answers suggests a minimal quote should be enough. The answer is undeleted.

Comment: "Is ferventcoder supposed to quote the official docs and also include a paraphrase of them " — I personally like having a summarization sentence to make it super clear at a glance what the answer is.  I'll also do this for any of my own answers that go into the depths of _why_ the answer is correct; basically a tldr that shows what to do, with more in depth "why" following.

Comment: @M.Justin If it's something big, a tldr maybe justified. This is just two to four lines, a summarization isn't justified. Also,  if the original author didn't add a tldr, edits would clearly conflict with the author's intent.

Comment: I am not sure I agree entirely with your *reasoning* there, @TheMaster - in particular, I think that's an excessively broad definition of "conflicts with the author's intent". But we do reach the same *conclusion* in this particular case; my stylistic preference is for the straightforward version you've [edited the answer to in revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29169135/revisions) rather than the revision before.

Comment: Getting into the (probably unimportant) details, I think the reason I'm not a fan of @M.Justin's summary in revision 8 is it's an awkward halfway between a comprehensive paraphrase of the answer and just an introduction to the quote. The summary isn't a usable answer on its own because necessary details are omitted (where do I put this `.ignore` file? What do I name it?). But if it's just meant to be an intro that leads into the quote that actually has the answer, why bother with details like the file being empty? More succinct: *"Use a `.ignore` file. As stated in the docs... <quote>"*

Comment: I do think this is just a subjective and debatable matter of good style, though, and I don't endorse looking at it through the lens of the site's editing rules. We are all just aiming for a good, polished answer, here, and perhaps we're in tension with each other due to differing stylistic opinions, but nobody benefits from pulling out the rulebook.

Comment: @MarkAmery Incidentally, I think I like your 3-word intro better than my longer one (mostly for the reason you stated).  It still gets across to solution at an immediate glance, and makes it clear that the rest of this particular answer is worth paying attention to when quickly scanning through answers.

Comment: Isn't `Use a .ignore file.` basically just a repetition of the following two to three lines? Also, why should anyone else edit into OP's post their personal style preference? Anyway, at least for this answer, I don't think we should add anything else, for the sake of meta, as it sets precedence, that such quote only answers are fine.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, it is a repetition.  However, it's a repetition in an easily scanned, four-word summary that stands out from a multiparagraph blockquote without making the post overly noisy.  If I'm scanning through a question with lots of answers, being able to quickly get the gist of an answer to see if it's an approach I want to pursue is helpful.  This isn't a deal breaker by any means, but i feel it's a "nice to have".

Answer (score 90):

The answer's first accusation was plagiarism. Given that the answer linked and sourced the content, this accusation should be thrown out. The author of the post [was also active with repo during that time](https://github.com/chocolatey-archive/chocolatey/graphs/contributors?from=2014-01-03&to=2015-10-03&type=c). Most probably, He quoted himself.

That leaves us with the second accusation: "Link only post, entirely quoted from external source".

The [deletion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) says:

> Answer posts that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.

There are six clauses written explaining what doesn't "fundamentally answer" the question. The only clause that's relevant here is the fifth one:

> barely more than a link to an external site

One could accuse the answer of being "just more than a link". But the guidelines explains this clause further:

> (i.e. the actual answer is not included in the post)

The actual answer is actually present in this post. If the answer only presented a link and said "Go here and read", I  would say that's "barely more than a link" and should be deleted. But this is no where near such a scenario. It's a focussed answer to a question, which even users unfamiliar with the subject can understand. It should not have been deleted at all, especially not by a  single vote. Given the upvotes, it also significantly added value to the community.

Then, there's [another guideline in the plagiarism section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

> "In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) **will often be deleted** since they do not contain any original content."

Even if we were to follow the letter of the law, rather than the spirit, the rules allow leeway in this case. **"Often" here doesn't mean "always"**. It implies that there are cases where it'll be left alone or another action should be taken, such as editing to improve the post. This answer is a prime example where ruling in favor of leaving it alone, is more than reasonable. The question is already linking the documentation and asking questions about it. The answer is quoting the documentation. What difference or what value would be added to the answer, if the poster (who probably is the author of the original quote) repeated the same in different words?

Comment: "Will often" doesn't necessarily mean "there are cases where it will be left in situ"; it could (and likely does) mean that in some cases different action might be taken, such as a member of the community making effort to improve the post to contain more than simply a quote from an off-site resource.

Comment: @Larnu What improvement would you suggest here?

Comment: As a non-SME I can't answer that; I'm disputing your statement that often means deleted or left alone, I'm not suggesting what could be done specifically improve the example, just that improvement is an option other than deletion.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not a SME either.  However, the question and answer is clear to me. Any edit(s) repeating the same quote would be superfluous and redundant. Improvement is a option, if possible. In this specific case however, "leaving it alone" seems to be the only remaining option, IMO.

Comment: @TheMaster deletion is *always* an option. If the content is truly valuable, it'll return.

Comment: @KevinB I would disagree. There are plenty of posts, which the meta would be glad to delete for various reasons, but those info are hard to come by. If it's truly valuable, valued more than the imaginary internet points gained by sharing that info, I believe it'll stay hidden. Market forces and supply demand will guide the final outcome. But, even if it does come back, why go through this delete-recreate cycle? It just means another poor soul is going to bang his head a few more days before figuring out his problem or give up trying.

Comment: @TheMaster it's simply a case of, follow the guidelines and your stuff won't be deleted. Don't, and it *might* be... regardless of how "valuable" some might find it. It is not unheard of for old highly upvoted *and blatantly incorrect or otherwise disallowed* content to be deleted here on SO. you simply don't often see it because... they're deleted.

Comment: @KevinB As I've explained, the plagiarism guidelines provide a leeway here.  There are also [deletion guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). I don't see how this answer would fulfill any of that criteria either.

Comment: It is clearly plagiarism. Plagiarism is disallowed. It meets all the requirements for such deletion. You are free to repost the answer in a form that isn't plagiarism. If it were the content you were worried about, surely that's the best way forward?

Comment: @KevinB Would you care to explain how it is plagiarism, when plagiarism is  [posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). I can see all indications that it is copied from github. (If anything, I think self promotion rules may apply, as I believe the author is the actual  originator of that quote) Yes, I care about the content, but I care more about the principle. That's why I'm making the answer in meta.

Comment: @TheMaster *"**Do not copy** the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (**sourced or not**) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."* There was no original content in that answer. Nothing in the answer was by the person posting it. Therefore, there's no problem with the answer being deleted for plagiarism.

Comment: You can certainly have an opinion that it shouldn't have been, given it doesn't say "MUST BE DELETED", however, that doesn't invalidate the mod's opinion that it should be.

Comment: @KevinB That's not the definition of plagiarism. That is a guideline on how to copy. And I still don't get how it violates the guideline either. "Do not copy the **complete text of sources**; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.".The author only quoted the relevant parts as written in "If you copy content that you did not create into something you post on Stack Overflow, make sure you do all of the following: Provide a link to the original page or answer, **Quote only the relevant portion**". It just so happened that in this case, there's nothing more to add after the quote.

Comment: It's a guideline on what kind of content might get deleted. it doesn't need to match the internet's definition of plagiarism to be valid.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's relevant that this case is not explicitly covered in the 6 bullet points in the [why answers are deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). That list is not meant to be exhaustive. e.g. Non-english answers, answers in a completely unrelated programming language, etc are not listed there either. Also, spam and rude content is not listed in those bullet points (though it is mentioned later). Answers without original content are also deleted, it's just another reason that's not explicitly listed here, that's all.

Comment: What? SO/SE rules that are not clear?? And are associated with institutionalized arbitrary (mis)interpretation?! I'm shocked! Shocked!

Comment: @cigien It's relevant as they serve as a baseline of what constitutes posts that don't "fundamentally answer" the question. Spam/rude flags are covered in that article "additionally". Everyone of your list is  about "fundamentally not answering the question" except the last one, "without original content".   Even without "original content", if it "fundamentally answers" the question, the official guidelines doesn't support deletion. Regardless, my point here, in this specific case, is that the quote covers everything already. There's no need to add something to pacify imaginary rule breaks.

Comment: @philipxy Not so sure if it is true institutionalisation. I think it is more that people default to the safest choices. If it smells like plagiarism... delete.

Comment: Is the pendulum finally swinging back requiring the answer to address the question asked?

Comment: Nice breakdown of the wording on the _/help/referencing_ page. That page obviously causes confusion even among moderators. Its title is about references, yet the first word is Plagiarism! This leads to a misconception that the entire page is about plagiarism. It isn't. Then the quoted paragraph from the OP conflates two different actions: "_Do not copy the complete text of sources... In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote..._" Copying 100% of a source and copying 100% of an answer are very different actions. "_In particular_" implies the two are related, but they are independent.

Answer (score 69):

[The answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18475/ferventcoder) is [the original author](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco-wiki/commit/14812a124b58994d77ab99282152b008e804ba9e) of those docs. He was quoting himself.

You can click through his SO profile to his GitHub account which has the same username and profile picture. It makes sense that he's answering questions on Chocolatey, given he's the guy who made it.

Is it technically a link-only answer? Sure, in as much as it doesn't add any additional content to the docs. But what additional content is FerventCoder supposed to supply? He's already considered and answered the question in the documentation he wrote. The only information worth adding is "RTFM"

Comment: They could have disclosed that they are the author, of course. That does produce quite a different situation than someone random building reputation off of someone else's work. (Given the broken link, it wasn't immediately clear that they were the original author)

Comment: I mean, to be fair it's all through the documentation, GitHub repo, the guy's GitHub profile, and his SO profile. You'd think deleting a +5 answer would prompt a bit more investigation than "he didn't say he was the original author in his answer"

Comment: Maybe that's a bit too snarky, I also understand how an answer like this could get deleted. I think in this instance it should be restored.

Comment: I think given the majority of the discussion that has occurred on this meta post, it's not unreasonable to expect people to not immediately make that connection, is all I'm saying. That certainly turns this into an exception

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Given we've all taken the time to look into it here, I reckon it should be restored.

Comment: @Joundill perhaps a flag on the A explaining that, with evidence?  Answer will need editing to disclose authorship though,  to avoid covert self promotion

Comment: @chrisneilsen I don't have the rep to see deleted answers. I agree with your suggestion to include authorship in an edit though

Comment: @Joundill then flag the Q?  Make it clear you're talking about a mod deleted A, and link this Q/A for context

Comment: To be clear, I'm not suggesting the lack of disclosure is a *reason* to delete in cases like this, rather, disclosure likely would have resulted in a different action in the first place.

Comment: That bit about `please disclose if your answer is about a product (free or not) that you develop`.

Comment: Disclosure is not required if the question is already about the product, see this [relevant question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371715/did-this-answer-require-the-op-to-disclose-affiliation)

Comment: Right, not required, however this is a great example of where providing it anyway can prevent problems.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the original source of the answer. There's an [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333708) about this, and the consensus appears to be that such answers are permitted. (The post is about copying an *answer* verbatim from somewhere else, but I expect the same to apply to copying documentation.) It also explicitly says attribution is not even required in such cases.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Fair comment, I won't flag the Q though, I assume a mod will have a read through this meta post and will make a decision on what to do about it.

Comment: *"Is it technically a link-only answer?"* - no, because it quotes the relevant content, and so isn't vulnerable to link rot. We call it a "link-only answer" when an answer *doesn't* do that, and therefore becomes useless if the linked page ever goes offline, but that's not the case here.

Comment: I updated the answer to state I am the author. Appreciate that it was restored.

Comment: It's not the fault of the author that the moderator didn't do rudimentary investigation. I'd also argue that it's not entirely the fault of the moderator given that it's not part of our process. The process should be amended to include a rudimentary investigation of authorship, substantiality (what % of the work is referenced), and notifying the original author to figure out if they want the content to stay or not. We shouldn't be deciding for someone else, what to do with their work if possible.

Comment: @ferventcoder we didn't ask Jon Skeet to say that he was the author of Java Time when he answered questions of Java Time. We are not going to ask you to do the same either. Authors do not need to add disclaimers, if they are answering questions relevant to what they are experts on. You are speaking from your position of expert on the topic. Now, if someone is asking how to solve a problem and you suggest your tool to solve that problem, that actually requires disclaimer, because you could be partial to your own tool.

Comment: @Braiam They are not directly speaking from their position of expert on the topic. *They are quoting*. Knowing that the quote *means* that they are speaking themselves *requires attribution*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi knowing what part of the documentation is relevant requires you to know what does it means and how it applies to the context. Someone with zero knowledge can quote the documentation, yes, but not whenever it is relevant to the question nor how it is relevant.

Comment: The following footnote was deleted by editor @Braiam "Disclosure: I am the original author of the documentation I linked to above.” Isn't knowing who the author of the quoted piece appropriate and ethical? Shouldn't all citations be attributed? I don't understand the motivation: `We don't ask Jon Skeet to disclosure when he quotes documentation, we aren't going to start now.` Why wouldn't a visitor want to know if JSkeets was the author of a piece that he himself quotes at length? Ultimately, I believe the edit to be harmful. P.S I lack the necessary rep to rollback the edit.

Answer (score -16):

The content on Stack Overflow is licensed [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).  If the person posting an answer does not have the right to grant that license to the quoted content, that would be a problem that could justify deleting the answer.

In this case the answerer is also the author of the quoted material, so obviously they *do* have the right to grant the license.  But that would not be obvious to someone reviewing the answer without putting some effort into tracing the source.

Comment: If that were a problem, then literally thousands of answers would have to be deleted. Quoting the docs as part (or even most) of an answer is _exceptionally_ common.

Comment: @Clonkex literally thousands of answers probably do need to be deleted.

Comment: @KevinB In general, that's very true. But in the context of quoting the docs, I strongly disagree, whether it's legally correct or not.

Comment: @Clonkex: Perhaps Mark could make a better argument, that quoting docs as part of a larger answer that interprets it is fine and closer to fair use.  But *just* quoting them with a link, so that's the only content of your answer, is less justified.  I still don't think that's a great argument, but at least it wouldn't imply that many other kinds of answers need to be thrown out.

Comment: Referencing someone else's work does not affect the original copyright, so it's off topic to bring this up. Fair use applies regardless. 

The question is whether SO counts as education/research, the nature (factual), the amount and substantiality of the portion in relation to the text as a whole, as well as the effect of the use on the potential market or value of the work. 

If the copyright holder wants they can request a takedown notice, but I don't think we should eagerly remove it without doing some investigation. The author may support such usage and be harmed by removing it.

Comment: Specifically, as was the case here. Many authors of technical manuals want people to read them, and do not object to excerpts. Removing all content without the consent of the author is not meaningfully better than including without the consent of the author. Takedown notices exist for a reason, often the original author approves of the use of their work and this unilateral approach of removing anything they have written is not in their interest. The moderation should involve some rudimentary investigation around the substantiality, authorship, and notifying the author so they can choose.

Comment: @PeterCordes unless this is a forum of lawyers, I don't think we can successfully argue what constitutes fair use and what does not.  Either way I don't think fair use covers granting a new license to the quoted content.  Stack Overflow does not give you an option to post anything without granting the license.

Comment: Interesting point; fair use applies when quoting a copyrighted work in your own work, and that's fine.  But granting *license* for others to use modified portions of the new work obviously can't grant them license to the thing you were quoting.  e.g. if someone posted a reaction video where they pause the original frequently to talk about it, and released it under a CC license, potentially someone could strip out their commentary and get basically the original video they were reacting to. I'm not sure which step in that process fails, legally, but I'm not sure it's the granting of a CC license

Comment: One could argue that it's clear which parts of a CC-licensed work are actually fair-use quotes from another work, which isn't granted license.  So modifications of the CC-licensed work must continue to respect the original copyright, only including quotes in ways that are fair use.  That would justify answers quoting docs *and including explanation / interpretation*, but not answers that *only* quote docs.  Up to you which position you want to argue, that or what you're currently saying (all quotes of docs are a problem), but the current form certainly has my downvote as non-useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes you certainly don't seem to be alone in concluding my answer is non-useful, but that doesn't make it wrong.  I think too many people believe it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Comment: I'd be interested to see a question asked on law.SE or opensource.SE about quoting copyrighted works in a CC-BY-SA work, such as a Stack Overflow answer.  And whether it's understood that clearly-quoted material is *not* part of what's being licensed for others to modify and so on.

Comment: Also, I think @VoronoiPotato's point is good, that it's reasonable to assume that by default, authors of technical documentation want relevant snippets to be quoted in places where it's applicable, and are fine with this usage of their work unless they say otherwise. Legally speaking, that's on shaky ground, but I assume there haven't been any complaints, and it's a well known widespread practice to quote docs in SO answers.  At this point it's reasonable to assume that authors of manuals in general at least tacitly approve this, so it's not a matter of expecting to need "forgiveness" exactly.

Comment: @PeterCordes Something like https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50205 perhaps?

Comment: @cigien: Thanks for finding that. The opinions there all lean towards quotes as part of larger answer being totally fine.  (And explaining some details like the quoted parts not being something you can grant a license to, but the implication is that readers will realize that from the quoting). And some argue that even a quote-only answer is barely ok, due to the effort of finding the relevant thing to quote and putting it in the context of an answer to a question that it answers. But that's not clearly supported for a case where it's only a single quote from one source. So a useful distinction

Comment: I have no idea whether these kind of quote-only answers theoretically constitute copyright infringement or not, but either way, it's not our problem. Stack Overflow's approach is always to *not* proactively enforce third parties' copyrights, but instead to act only upon receipt of DMCA takedown requests. I think this is entirely the right approach, especially in cases where an answer is quoting public (but perhaps unlicensed) docs; even if such an answer is technically infringing copyright, *who cares*? The "infringement" is doing no harm to the original copyright holder in such a case.

Comment: Yep, also it gives far more control by the copyright holder, since if we are going to take it down they should at least be consulted.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato chances are the copyright holder will never hear about it, which explains why nobody seems to care.