# Answering on behalf of the company?

Tags: support, accounts, product-support

I got an internship offer from a software development company to work in the user support department. They are developing an open-source project. They would like for me to answer questions related to their software on one university forum, on Quora and here on Stack Overflow.

Do I need to use a company account for that, or am I even allowed to answer on behalf of the company?

Comment: As long as you do not share the account with other people, you are good. You can create a dedicated account or use your current one.

Comment: However, when answering questions please be mindful that you are doing it primarily for Stack Overflow, not for your company. This means that you should only answer questions that are actually useful for the community. Do not answer just any question. Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a support desk.

Comment: Note as well that just because you are answering on behalf on a company doesn't mean that you are "above" the rules or curation/quality processes; the quality of your content will be judged exactly the same, and if that quality doesn't meet expectations you could just as easily be on the end of an answer ban.  If such a thing happens, you won't be able to do your job any more, as creating a *new* account to get around that is against the rules.

Comment: I kind of wonder if as an intern you will have the knowledge and skill to answer questions that should be asked on Stack Overflow though. Stack Overflow is for programming problems, not for personal support. This is not a simple "yes", you'd have to be very familiar with the rules of Stack Overflow to be able to identify which questions not to answer, and to not abuse comments. Otherwise... just take a look at the last couple of weeks of meta posts, count how many "i've been banned from asking questions" posts there are.

Comment: (that's a little ambiguous I now realise: I mean as an indicator for how easy it is to see your privileges such as asking and answering questions revoked if you treat Stack Overflow in a way that is not intended).

Comment: Related (despite the title. It is about a Microsoft contractor doing something similar): *[Is it legitimate to mark (almost) all of your answers as "community wiki"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416882/is-it-legitimate-to-mark-almost-all-of-your-answers-as-community-wiki)*. And *[Microsoft Azure customer engineers giving low quality answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419331/)*.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SE has no rules against users identifying themselves as employees of a company. A lot of companies have "official" accounts they use to interact with "their" userbase here.

So, as long as you're not *impersonating* someone, you'll be fine.

Just make sure you're not advertising the product, as that could be considered spam, which isn't tolerated.

Comment: Maybe noting that in certain cases [disclosure is required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371715/did-this-answer-require-the-op-to-disclose-affiliation) would be useful.

Comment: This is a good thing to know. I'll add one if I accept the internship offer.

Answer (score 10):

*(While I'm an employee of Stack, I'm answering this in a non-official capacity.  Any CMs or Mods answers should be taken as truth over this one).*

While it's totally fine to answer questions on behalf of your employer, it's best not to have a "company account".  The [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#obligations) state that accounts should be tied to *individuals*.  This is, in part, due to the content of questions and answers being licensed under the CC, which are attributed to the author.

> To access some of the public Network features you will need to register for an account as an individual and consent to these Public Network Terms.

Comment: What about an *individual* company account.  That is, you have your normal account, like JohnDoe, and then your individual work account, such as JohnDoeAtMicroBrand.  I don't really know why someone would want to do that, but is it acceptable?

Comment: yes, that's acceptable, as long as you aren't using one user to upvote or improperly "promote" the other user. (ie: don't game the system - you'll get banned). In this case, both users are still tied to a single person.  The thing to avoid is a "MicroBrand Support" account where a whole bunch of employees share a username/password.

Comment: So this means that there can be an account "ACMEltd," but just one user can use it? It has to be a personal account but it can have a company name. I'll try to check with them how it goes with their branding rules.